# ngClass: using && operator Parser Error: Missing Expected : at column X,

Tags: angular6

I am trying to use `&&` inside the condition of ngClass :

My block of code is :

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 form-group " [ngClass]="{has-error : (!CountryName.valid && CountryName.touched)}">
                        <label class="control-label">Country Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CountryName" placeholder="Country name" maxlength="50" minlength="5" required 
                               ngModel #CountryName="ngModel" />

                    </div>
```

& i get this error :

> ERROR in : Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 5 in [{has-error
>   : (!CountryName.valid && CountryName.touched)}] in
>   C:/Abdul/TestProjects/Angular6CRUDAPI/Angular6CRUDAPI/src/app/masters/country-master/country-add-2/country-add-2.component.html@23:64
>   ("

I know I am doing some silly mistake which i am unable to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Got It : `has-error` should be in quotes

as

```
 [ngClass]="{'has-error' : (!CountryName.valid && CountryName.touched)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

"if using dash in class name, must be using single quotation marks into ngClass or rename the class name without dash symbol"
Like

`[ngClass]="{'has-error' : (!CountryName.valid && CountryName.touched)}`

or

`[ngClass]="{haserror : (!CountryName.valid && CountryName.touched)}`